# How and why is the work done by magnetic field zero in this case

Tags: electromagnetism, work, electromagnetic-induction

I saw the following case recently

[image: 1]

The rod is given a velocity $v$ rightwards. Due to change in flux current will be flowing in the wire. Now work done by magnetic field using $q(v\times b)$ is certainly zero, however another force is acting on the wire which is now carrying induced current, opposite to direction of velocity given by $l(i \times b)$ in this case the dot product of the direction of force due to magnetic field and the displacement of the rod is certainly not zero, however the solution says it should be zero as it is in most cases. Why is the work done due to magnetic field zero in this case?

Comment: This is an exact repeat of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93109/work-done-by-lorentz-force-in-case-of-motional-emf?rq=1 . See the discussion there.